# Border css for html table

Tags: html, css

I have two tables, one with the id ='data'. My question is that i want to apply the below border properties for the table id='data' only but from the below code the css is being applied to both the tables.How to correct this

```
<style>
table
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
table#data,th,td
{
   border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What are you trying to put the border on? The table, or the th and td elements?

Comment: Hint: you can't abbreviate selectors. Everything separated by commas are applied as is.

Comment: by bellow border property, do you mean wish to border-bottom property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
#data,
#data th,
#data td
{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

because with `table` in the CSS selector You're gonna call all tables, unless You specify a class like `table.class { ... }` ;)

**// edit**

ok, i have to say:

```
table#data,
table#data th,
table#data td
{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

will work also...

the main thing is, that You specify the ID or class of Your desired element in the CSS to get Your style applied to Your desired element...

Comment: This soled the issue .Thanks